# Is revtex documentclass compatible with glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, revtex, glossaries-extra

I would like to use the `documentclass` `revtex4` and in it I would like to use the package `glossaries-extra`.

Unfortunately, when I put the two together, I get the following message: `Error: Missing \glsxtr@resource in aux file. (Have you used \glsxtrresourcefile or \GlsXtrLoadResources?) system returned with code 768`.

And it looks like, the `glossaries-extra` package is not able to find my entries, but I do not see why it should not work, I use the same kind of code for many documents (with `\documentclass{article}` for example) without any trouble.

Here is my minimal non-working example `aipsamp-test.tex`:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes, interaction: batchmode }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes, interaction: batchmode }

%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\documentclass[%
        aip,
        amsmath, amssymb,
        reprint,% Neither reprint nor twocolumn options work.
%       twocolumn,
    ]{revtex4-2} % or revtex4-1.
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \begin{filecontents}{SymbolsAcronymsTest.bib}
        @acronym{fem,short= {FEM}, long= {Finite Element Method}}
        
        @symbol{dens,
            name={\ensuremath{ \rho }},
            description={mass density},
        }
    \end{filecontents}

    \newcommand{\PathSymbolsEntries}{./SymbolsAcronymsTest}%.bib
    \usepackage[record, automake]{glossaries-extra}
        \newglossary*{acronym}{Abbreviations}
        \newglossary*{symbol}{Nomenclature}
            
        \GlsXtrLoadResources[
            src={\PathSymbolsEntries}, 
            type={acronym},
            match={entrytype=acronym},
        ]
        
        \GlsXtrLoadResources[
            src={\PathSymbolsEntries},
            type=symbol,
            match={entrytype=symbol},
        ]
        
\begin{document}
    \title{Sample Title}
    \author{A. Author}
    \date{\today}
    \begin{abstract}
        An article usually includes an abstract. 
    \end{abstract}
    \maketitle

    \section{First-level heading}
        This sample document demonstrates proper use of REV. 
        $\gls{dens}$, \gls{fem}

    \printunsrtglossary[type=acronym]
    \printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]
\end{document}
```

Is there known incompatibilities ? Or do you have any ideas ?
Thanks by advance.

## Edit

The issue is clearly seen through the shell command:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape ./aipsamp-test.tex 1>log.txt
pdflatex --shell-escape ./aipsamp-test.tex 1>log.txt
Error: Missing \glsxtr@resource in aux file. (Have you used \glsxtrresourcefile or \GlsXtrLoadResources?)
system returned with code 768
```

Also as the previous command shows it the error does not stop the compilation but just gives a warning in the terminal. So the problem does not appear in the logfile. Therefore, I think that the problem comes from the `glossaries-extra` internal `runsystem(bib2gls aipsamp-test)` from the `automake` option.

Otherwise in the produced document, the section Acronym and Nomenclature are empty and there is question mark where rho and FEM should appear, as it can be seen in red in the screenshot below.[image]

Here is the log file `aipsamp-test.log` generated:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.17)  17 SEP 2020 16:58
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./aipsamp-test.tex
(./aipsamp-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/re
vtex/ for documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2019 American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>Version (4.2c)
: Modified by Mark Doyle
 .
ltxutil[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 315.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 365.
\eqncolsep=\skip47
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfoot
note on input line 440.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 762.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count167
\@tbpen=\count168
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box45
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1793.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2053.
ltxfront[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
\c@affil=\count169
\c@collab=\count170
\absbox=\box46
ltxgrid[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count171
\output@latex=\toks15
\box@size@1=\box47
\box@size@2=\box48
\@protection@box=\box49
\@topmark@saved=\toks16
\footins@saved=\box50
\footins@recovered=\box51
\column@recovered=\box52
\pagesofar=\box53
\footsofar=\box54
\pagegrid@col=\count172

Class revtex4-2 Warning: Failed to recognize \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@
newline, and \\; no patches applied. Please get a more up-to-date class, .

\c@part=\count173
\c@section=\count174
\c@subsection=\count175
\c@subsubsection=\count176
\c@paragraph=\count177
\c@subparagraph=\count178
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count179
\fbox@1=\box55
\c@table=\count180
\fbox@2=\box56
\c@video=\count181
\fbox@4=\box57
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box58
\widetext@bot=\box59
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting society aip on input line 7581.
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aip4-2.rtx
File: aip4-2.rtx 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c AIP substyle for REVTeX
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX society AIP selected on input line 87.
)

Class revtex4-2 Warning: No journal specified, using default cha.

Using journal substyle cha.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Reading file aps10pt4-2.rtx on input line 7586.
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for
 documentation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 36.
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding 10pt on input line 7586.

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen134
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen135
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count182
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count183
\leftroot@=\count184
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count185
\DOTSCASE@=\count186
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box60
\strutbox@=\box61
\big@size=\dimen136
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count187
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count188
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count189
\dspbrk@lvl=\count190
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count191
\column@=\count192
\maxfields@=\count193
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen137
\alignsep@=\dimen138
\tagshift@=\dimen139
\tagwidth@=\dimen140
\totwidth@=\dimen141
\lineht@=\dimen142
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip53
\bibsep=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count194
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7588.

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ 
for documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 101.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 117.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 125.
))
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks23
\inpenc@posthook=\toks24
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)

LaTeX Warning: File `SymbolsAcronymsTest.bib' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.


(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-extra/glossaries-e
xtra.sty
Package: glossaries-extra 2020/03/23 v1.44 (NLCT)
 (/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks25
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks26

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count195
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count196
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.st
y
Package: glossaries 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
 (/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
\@glsmfirst=\toks27
\@glsmrest=\toks28
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count197
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count198
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count199
\FP@xia=\count266
\FP@xib=\count267
\FP@xfa=\count268
\FP@xfb=\count269
\FP@rega=\count270
\FP@regb=\count271
\FP@regs=\count272
\FP@times=\count273
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count274
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks29
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count275
\dtl@tmplength=\skip55
\dtl@sortresult=\count276
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count277
\@dtl@datatype=\count278
\dtl@codeA=\count279
\dtl@codeB=\count280
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count281
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-co
mpatible-307.sty
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count282
\@gls@tmpb=\toks30
\gls@tmplen=\skip56
\glskeylisttok=\toks31
\glslabeltok=\toks32
\glsshorttok=\toks33
\glslongtok=\toks34

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hy
pernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-li
st.sty
Package: glossary-list 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip57
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-lo
ng.sty
Package: glossary-long 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
 (/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip58
\LTright=\skip59
\LTpre=\skip60
\LTpost=\skip61
\LTchunksize=\count283
\LTcapwidth=\dimen143
\LT@head=\box62
\LT@firsthead=\box63
\LT@foot=\box64
\LT@lastfoot=\box65
\LT@cols=\count284
\LT@rows=\count285
\c@LT@tables=\count286
\c@LT@chunks=\count287
\LT@p@ftn=\toks35
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip62
\glspagelistwidth=\skip63
)
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-su
per.sty
Package: glossary-super 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count288
\ST@wd=\dimen144
\ST@rightskip=\skip64
\ST@leftskip=\skip65
\ST@parfillskip=\skip66
\ST@pageleft=\dimen145
\ST@headht=\dimen146
\ST@tailht=\dimen147
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen148
\ST@pboxht=\dimen149
\ST@lineht=\dimen150
\ST@prevht=\dimen151
\ST@toadd=\dimen152
\ST@dimen=\dimen153
\ST@pbox=\box66
))
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tr
ee.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip67
))
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-extra/glossaries-e
xtra-bib2gls.sty
Package: glossaries-extra-bib2gls 2020/03/23 v1.44 (NLCT)
)
\@glsxtr@leveloffset=\count289
\glsxtrresourcecount=\count290
\@glsxtrnewgls@inner=\count291
\glsshortpltok=\toks36
\glslongpltok=\toks37
)
runsystem(bib2gls aipsamp-test)...executed.



Package glossaries-extra Warning: No file `aipsamp-test.glstex' on input line 3
3.


Package glossaries-extra Warning: No file `aipsamp-test-1.glstex' on input line
 39.

Class revtex4-2 Info: Unrecognized LaTeX tabular. Please update this document c
lass! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 41.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Patching unrecognized longtable package. (Proceeding with
 fingers crossed) on input line 41.
Class revtex4-2 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 41.
Class revtex4-2 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 41.
Class revtex4-2 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 41.

(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.d
ef
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count292
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box67
) (./aipsamp-test.aux)
\openout1 = `aipsamp-test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 41.
\openout3 = `aipsamp-testNotes.bib'.



Class revtex4-2 Warning: Assuming \noaffiliation for authors.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmss on input line 4
8.
(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd
File: t1cmss.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 52.


(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 52.


(/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary entry `dens' has not been defined on
 input line 52.


Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary entry `fem' has not been defined on 
input line 52.


Package glossaries-extra Warning: No entries defined in glossary `acronym' on i
nput line 54.


Package glossaries-extra Warning: No entries defined in glossary `symbol' on in
put line 55.

No file aipsamp-test.bbl.
No file aipsamp-test.bbl.
[1{/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./aipsamp-test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9602 strings out of 480608
 149647 string characters out of 5901651
 505453 words of memory out of 5000000
 25383 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 540170 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 59i,4n,41p,1053b,329s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/c
m-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/cm-super/sfrm0900.pfb></Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb></Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/cm-super/sfss1000.pfb></Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts/t
ype1/public/cm-super/sfsx0900.pfb></Applis/TexLive/texlive2020/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1440.pfb>
Output written on aipsamp-test.pdf (1 page, 75208 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 23 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I continued the investigations and it seems that the problem comes from the option `reprint` in the `\documentclass`: by commenting this option, the compilation returns no error and the document looks like expected. However, the layout is completely different without this option. I also notice the same problem with the option `twocolumn`. But the question about why these options generate troubles remains ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @egreg 
Did you uncomment the reprint option ?

Comment: Yes, I did. The only thing I changed was the name of the `.bib` file (so I don't risk clobbering my files).

Comment: @egreg Humm, interesting ! Because, I tried many times and this problem persist, on my computer. So, could it be version dependent ? I am using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)`

Comment: @egreg, I updated my TexLive with the 2020 version, but the problem remains. I also edit my question by adding some precisions about how detect the problem. Hoping you will be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either, please provide the full log from a compilation via texlive 2020. We mostly need it to see if you have old package versions interferring. I get several warnings, but no compilation errors. Also note that you can include the data file into the example using the `filecontents` env

Comment: @daleif, I edit my question to include the log file. I think that people will prefer to have the logfile in the question rather than in a separated download. I agree about the `filecontents` environment, but I wanted to be as close as possible to my real usage. However, I can use the `filecontents` if you think it would be better.

Comment: When ever possible we nevr want stuff on external URLs as they tend to rot over time.

Comment: Pleae provide the log and MWE that gives that error. I also wonder about those `Class revtex4-1 Info: Unrecognized LaTeX tabular. Please update this document c
lass! ` lines, I don't seem to get those with a fully up to date TL2020.

Comment: @daleif, I edited my post. If I use `revtex4-2`, which is the latest version, the problem remains. In my post both the log and MWE are those which gives the error, but as I added, the error is not stopping the compilation and not visible in the log. So I think the error message comes from the internal `runsystem`. And as result after 2 `pdflatex` compilation there is nomenclature nor acronym section.

Comment: Is there still nobody that can reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is essentially that

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\gdef\string\foo{bar}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
A
\end{document}
```

does not write out `\gdef \foo{bar}` to the aux file.
I don't know why, it works when `twocolumn` is not active, it also works if `\maketitle` is omitted, it works if some text is typeset before `\maketitle`, but if `\maketitle` is the first thing typeset in `twocolumn` certain calls to `\@auxout` don't show up.

I'd thought this might relate to the [new latex hooks](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/07/22/latex-dev-2020-10-1b/) which revtex now uses with sufficiently recent versions of latex, but testing on Overleaf I seem to be able to replicate this back to TL 2014 (as far as Overleaf goes) with `revtex4` and `revtex4-1`.

While most of the aux file comes out correctly, the `\glsxtr@resource` that `\GlsXtrLoadResources` should've written doesn't, under the hood it uses `\protected@write\@auxout` to generate it.  With a couple of patches to `\GlsXtrLoadResources` and `\glsxtrresourcefile` we can delay writing out to the aux file until `\end{document}` where they are written out successfully.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes, interaction: batchmode }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes, interaction: batchmode }

\begin{filecontents}{SymbolsAcronymsTest.bib}
@acronym{fem,short= {FEM}, long= {Finite Element Method}}

@symbol{dens,
    name={\ensuremath{ \rho }},
    description={mass density},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[record,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossary*{acronym}{Abbreviations}
\newglossary*{symbol}{Nomenclature}

\makeatletter
% patch some recent changes to the \GlsXtrLoadResources and
% \glsxtrresourcefile macros so the redefinitions below should
% also work with earlier versions of glossaries-extra
\providecommand{\glsindexingsetting}{}
\providecommand{\glsxtr@save@mfu}{}

\renewcommand*{\GlsXtrLoadResources}[1][]{%
  \ifnum\glsxtrresourcecount=0\relax
    \glsxtrresourcefile[#1]{\jobname}%
  \else
    \edef\glsxtrresourcefilename{\jobname-\the\glsxtrresourcecount}% <--- ADDED
    \glsxtrresourcefile[#1]{\glsxtrresourcefilename}% <--- MODIFIED
  \fi
  \advance\glsxtrresourcecount by 1\relax
}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrresourcefile}[2][]{%
 \@glsxtr@if@record@only
 {\renewcommand{\glsindexingsetting}{bib2gls}}%
 {\edef\glsindexingsetting{bib2gls-\ifglsxindy xindy\else makeindex\fi}}%
  \disable@keys{glossaries-extra.sty}{record}%
  \glsxtr@writefields
  \glsxtr@save@mfu
  \ifdefempty\GlsXtrDefaultResourceOptions
  {%
  \AtEndDocument{% <--- ADDED
    \protected@write\@auxout{\glsxtrresourceinit}%
    {\string\glsxtr@resource{#1}{#2}}%
  }% <--- ADDED
  }%
  {%
  \AtEndDocument{% <--- ADDED
   \protected@write\@auxout{\glsxtrresourceinit}%
    {\string\glsxtr@resource{\GlsXtrDefaultResourceOptions,#1}{#2}}%
  }% <--- ADDED
  }%
  \let\@glsxtr@org@see@noindex\@gls@see@noindex
  \let\@gls@see@noindex\relax
  \IfFileExists{#2.glstex}%
  {%
    \edef\@bibgls@restoreat{\noexpand\catcode\noexpand`\noexpand\@=\number\catcode`\@}%
    \makeatletter
    \@input{#2.glstex}%
    \@bibgls@restoreat
    \@glsxtr@check@bibgls@nameref
  }%
  {%
    \GlossariesExtraWarning{No file `#2.glstex'}%
  }%
  \let\@gls@see@noindex\@glsxtr@org@see@noindex
}
\makeatother

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={./SymbolsAcronymsTest},
  type={acronym},
  match={entrytype=acronym},
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={./SymbolsAcronymsTest},
  type={symbol},
  match={entrytype=symbol},
]


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\gls{dens}, \gls{fem}

\printunsrtglossary[type=acronym]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled document showing both glossaries working]

Rather than messing with the internals of `glossaries-extra`, typesetting anything before `\maketitle` will also avert the problem, so

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\gdef\string\foo{bar}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rule{0pt}{0pt}
\maketitle
A
\end{document}
```

gives an accurate aux file, but this does noticeably push any  title matter down, inspite of the rule itself being zero size.

The dodgy aux file only seems to affect external calls (`makeglossaries`/`bib2gls`), so (as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654178/106162)) it is probably sufficient to switch to `onecolumn` and compile once before making those external calls and then reverting to `twocolumn` afterwards. This will need to be repeated whenever you want to update a glossary.

Comment: I tried your answer on my system, and I got the following error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \glsindexingsetting undefined.` `! Undefined control sequence.
\\glsxtrresourcefile ...tefields \glsxtr@save@mfu \ifdefempty \GlsXtrDefault... l.70 ]`. So which TeX compiler are you using and which version ?

Comment: This was based on v1.50 of `glossaries-extra`, internals must've changed.  Which version do you have? I'll see if I can rewrite more flexibly to use `\patchcmd` or work out how to adapt it otherwise.

Comment: I am using `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)`

Comment: @R.N I've updated the example to work with earlier versions of glossaries-extra, this compiles for me across TL 2020–2023.  Let me know if you have any further problems.

Comment: I checked your 2 solutions, and they are both working fine. Of course the second is quicker.

Comment: Yes, much simpler, but unfortunately I can't find anything that will trigger the aux writes without adding additional vertical space before the title (while the `\rule` itself is zero-height and not visible, its presence noticeably displaces the title).